# pop-up polygons in blender

Tags: blender, artifacts

I have a problem, after updating Blender to 4.0, it turned out that my card does not support Open GL 4.3, so I went back to the old version of Blender (3.6), but something broke and it doesn't work as it should. When I run it, the processor runs at 100% and Blender shows artifacts. Uninstalling and installing did not help, nor did updating the graphics card.the only version that works normally 2.79b ,I also tested other guides and this portal, but it doesn't work [enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xadGv.jpg)
I have Windows 10
Intel Xeon W3550
Radeon HD 7500

I deleted the blender folder from %appdata%
updating drivers to newer and older ones
I tested all versions of blender, only 2.79b works for me
I restored the default settings